# How to pass python generator object from one Airflow task to another?

Tags: python, generator, airflow

I'm trying to pass a generator object obtained from a generator function that has a yield statement. I have some code that runs before the yeild and some code that runs after the yield. I wanted to create two Airflow tasks where the code before yeild would run in one task and the code after the yield would run in the second task. So, for this case how can I pass generator object from one task to other? Airflow XCOM does not work as a python generator object cannot be pickled.

For Example:

```py
#Generator function
def greet_world():
    print("Hello World!")
    yield 
    print("Goodbye world!")
```

The statement "Hello World!" should be executed in the first Airflow task and the second statement "Goodbye world!" should be executed in the second Airflow task.

Comment: Why can't you make it two separate functions?

Comment: I have a use case where I'm using generator fucntions to create tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure why that was an answer to Klaus's question. If you want two tasks, why not use two generators?